# I want to run pict.exe from a java program

Tags: java, process, runtime, executable

PICT generates test cases and test configurations. https://github.com/microsoft/pict

I want to run the executable `pict.exe` through a java program. I tried using `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`, it ran without any errors but no output file was generated.

```
package com.test.CommandLine;

public class CommandLineTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String execPath = "resources\\pict.exe";
        String param = "resources\\CarOrderApp.txt > resources\\CarOrderApp.xls";

        runPict(execPath, param);
    }

    public static void runPict(String execPath, String param) {
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execPath + " " + param);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() + "\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my project Structure:

[image]

Comment: It's probably because the I/O redirection `>` is a bash operator that is not recognised here.

Comment: Running the same from cmd works just fine  :
resources\pict.exe resources\\CarOrderApp.txt > resources\\CarOrderApp.xls

Comment: Yes, but that is because `cmd` interpretes that > char in that case. PIPING commands dont work like that when you use the exec (or ProcessBuilder, because you shouldnt use exec in the first place)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to define output instead of using cmd `>` redirect operator:

```
String execPath = "resources\\pict.exe";
String inPath = "resources\\CarOrderApp.txt";
String outPath = "resources\\CarOrderApp.xls";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(execPath, inPath);
builder.redirectOutput(new File(outPath));
Process p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks! It works as expected now.